# T440s Stops Booting into GRUB after a random period of time

Tags: boot, grub2, encryption, ssd

I have a new Thinkpad T440s. Here are my specifications:

Intel 4600U
12GB (4GB integrated, 8GB stick) DDR3 1600 
Samsung 840 SSD 250GB
Sandisk SSD 16GB

This problem has been a real brain buster as I can't pinpoint the cause. Basically I will install Ubuntu with full disk encryption onto the Samsung 840 SSD. The OS works great, no crashes, totally smooth, great battery life. It works absolutely great.

Then, seemingly out of nowhere, the laptop will fail to boot. It does *not* appear to get  to GRUB (much less the screen where you put in your decryption passphrase). In fact, it gets stuck on the screen where you choose a device to boot from almost as though GRUB is gone.

[Here's the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38w0Q.jpg)

As far as I can tell no one else is having this issue. I was wondering if anyone here had some insight as to what could be happening?

Things I've done so far:

1. Reinstalled multiple times
2. Upgraded the BIOS to latest version
3. Disabled UEFI/Secureboot

Things I'm thinking of doing:

1. Reinstalling with no encryption
2. Replacing SSD

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? Do you use Hardware Encryption or Ubuntu Encryption? Please also note, that Grub is using an hidden timeout countdown by default.
I can also see the Signature of Windows Boot Manager. You should remove that, if you're not using dual boot over the UEFI-Bootmanager.